# ¿Cómo guardar un modelo DecisionTreeClassifier MLlib de Spark en formato ONNX?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark, databricks

En el siguiente código de python:

```py
#Entrenamiento del modelo:

*model_clas=DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='Clasificacion_OBJ',maxDepth=5,maxBins=20,minInstancesPerNode=1,impurity = impurity,seed=25).fit(model_df)

#Guardado del modelo:

mlflow.spark.save_model(model_clas,'Repos/daniel.masip.../model_clas/')*
```

Entreno un modelo de clasificación y lo guardo usando la librería `mlflow`.

Pero yo quiero guardar el modelo en formato `ONNX`.

Necesito POR FAVOR una explicación fácil y sencilla, porque todo lo que encuentro en internet es inentendible.
Gracias.
Daniel

Comment: Podrias partir por contarnos que encontrastes y hasta donde llegaste. Eso da un punto de partida para responder.

Comment: Encontré esto:

https://github.com/onnx/onnxmltools/blob/main/onnxmltools/convert/sparkml/README.md

Pero no entiendo nada del funcionamiento de ese código. Necesito algo fácil y sencillo. Gracias por preguntar.

Comment: Lo que te dice ahí es que primero crees una lista de tuplas, la tupla se compone de 2 valores, el nombre y el tipo de tensor que tienes. En el segundo paso solo usas esa lista en la función que te proveen y en el tercer paso lo guardas.

Comment: Hola @Christian, me alegra mucho que lo veas tan fácil. Ahora sería posible explicar cómo de lo que yo tengo se guarda MI modelo en ONNX. (Fácil y sencillo) Gracias de nuevo :)